# Liferay Portal 6.2 CE struts.jar (version1) to struts2.*.jar (upgrade issue)

Tags: liferay-6

I am trying to upgrade Liferay Portal 6.2 ce struts 1 to  struts2.*.jar, please advise on how this can be done as it is not direct replace of struts.jar with struts latest version, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is not as simple as just swapping jars.

Struts 1 to Struts 2 represents a fundamental change of the library.

You can pursue changing your own code to use Struts 2 instead of Struts 1, but if you're asking how to change Liferay's use of Struts 1 to use Struts 2 instead, that is a much harder task as it would require making fundamental changes to the Liferay core.

If your concern is simply removing Struts 1 because of published vulnerabilities, they are false positives with respect to Liferay.  Liferay uses Struts 1 internally for request dispatching, but it does not expose or use Struts 1 components (such as Struts 1 forms) which have demonstrated vulnerabilities.  So while Liferay uses Struts 1, it does not suffer from the vulnerabilities that Struts 1 has.